# Uploading to S3, how can I tell if it was a successful transfer?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im uploading some images to S3, how can I check if it was a successful transfer?

Here is my code. I screw up the access key on purpose so the files do not upload, how can I catch this error and act upon it?

The code below does not catch anything, even though the images fail to upload.

```
$this->commands[] = $this->s3->getCommand('PutObject', [
        'Bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'Key' => $name,
        'Body' => $img,
        'ContentType' => $mime,
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ]);

$pool = new CommandPool($this->s3, $this->commands);

$promise = $pool->promise();

try {
    $result = $promise->wait();
}
catch (AwsException $e) {
    var_dump($e)
}
```

Im using php sdk 3.0

Comment: Are you using the AWS SDk for php ? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html

Comment: Yes, I am, as stated in question. but v3.0 Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, and URL of the object is returned once the upload is finished. Probably the best is to check the MD5 schecksum of the uploaded object against the checksum of the object on your computer. These two should match if the upload was successful.

Answer (score 7):

I am also using PHP SDK 3.0 and was able to get the result of the upload using the following:

```
$result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucketName,
    'Key'    => $backupFileName,
    'SourceFile' => $backupFile,
));

$code = $result['@metadata']['statusCode'];
$uri = $result['@metadata']['effectiveUri'];

if ($code === 200) {
    // Success code here
}
```